# Autotools PKG_CHECK_MODULES isn't setting variables

Tags: c, makefile, autotools

My first autotools project, might be something simple and dumb: it's creating a makefile that can't find glib and other 3rd party libraries. (Running Ubuntu Linux, compiling a C static library if that matters.)

Configure.ac includes these lines:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libglib], [glib-2.0 >= 2.28])
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libobject], [gobject-2.0 >= 2.28])
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libuuid], [uuid])
```

Makefile.am is as follows

```
lib_LIBRARIES=libblah.a
libblah_a_SOURCES=blah.c util.c
libblah_a_CPPFLAGS=$(libglib_CFLAGS) $(libobject_CFLAGS) $(libuuid_CFLAGS)
libblah_a_LIBADD=$(libglib_LIBS) $(libobject_LIBS) $(libuuid_LIBS)
```

Running autoreconf --install generates Makefile.in with this:

```
libglib_CFLAGS = @libglib_CFLAGS@
libglib_LIBS = @libglib_LIBS@
libobject_CFLAGS = @libobject_CFLAGS@
libobject_LIBS = @libobject_LIBS@
libuuid_CFLAGS = @libuuid_CFLAGS@
libuuid_LIBS = @libuuid_LIBS@
```

Looks good! Except then the configure script claims it found these libraries yet spits out a Makefile that converts the above line into this uselessness:

```
libglib_CFLAGS = 
libglib_LIBS = 
libobject_CFLAGS = 
libobject_LIBS = 
libuuid_CFLAGS = 
libuuid_LIBS =
```

Help!

Edit: Here is the full configure.ac file:

```
AC_INIT([amblah], [1.0], [bug-automake@gnu.org])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
 Makefile
 libblah/Makefile
 tests/Makefile
])
AC_OUTPUT
AC_PROG_RANLIB
PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG(0.26)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libglib], [glib-2.0 >= 2.28])
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libobject], [gobject-2.0 >= 2.28])
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libuuid], [uuid])
```

Comment: What output do you get when you run `pkg-config` directly?

Comment: Perhaps you are running the configure script with in sane mode with `PKG_CONFIG=true`.  (Note that this is somewhat tongue-in-cheek: PKG_CONFIG=true effectively disables PKG_CHECK_MODULES and requires the user to assign LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS correctly.)

Comment: Is this just missing `AC_SUBST(XXX_CFLAGS)` and `AC_SUBST(XXX_LIBS)` for those libraries?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: `pkg-config` detects the libraries. I was using it with my handcrafted Makefile before attempting the migration to autotools. Example, `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` gives `-lglib-2.0`. As for PKG_CONFIG, I'm not explicitly setting it anywhere. A grep of the files shows this in config.log: `PKG_CONFIG='/usr/bin/pkg-config'`.

Comment: @EtanReisner: I'm not familiar with AC_SUBST. I'll add the full configure.ac file above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! I see the problem, and it is definitely a dumb newb problem. AC_OUTPUT is what makes it spit out Makefile output and so forth. The GNU tutorial wasn't clear on this fact, and I had put some lines below AC_OUTPUT. Thus those lines were not considered when AC_OUTPUT generated its output. By moving AC_OUTPUT to the very end, it fixes the problem.